# Sitecore Commerce Plugin.Sample.Notes EntityVersion issue

Tags: sitecore-commerce

If anyone follows the Sitecore KB article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/083614, "How to extend Catalog system entities schema in Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0", you may encounter the issue where your plugin does not update correctly. I was able to load the plug in and make edits, but the main sellable item user interface was not updating correctly.

Comment: You answered your question in the question.. Try editing to move the answer to an actual answer and mark that one as the actual answer. This way we know your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it was updating entityversion 1 in the database; not the current version I was working with. I tracked this back to a section in code in the Get[PlugInName]ViewBlock. This was corrected by adding the EntityVersion field in the code section below:

```
var view = new EntityView
                {
                    Name = context.GetPolicy<Known[PluginName]ViewsPolicy>().[PluginName],
                    DisplayName = "[PluginName]",
                    EntityId = arg.EntityId,
                    ItemId = variationId,
                    EntityVersion = arg.EntityVersion
                };
```